# How do you call short numbers (eg. 911) on Messenger Platform?

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

According to Facebook Messenger documentation for the [Call Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/call-button), you have to keep the following format in your payload for the call button to work:

> Format must have "+" prefix followed by the country code, area code
>   and local number. For example, +16505551234.

Any other format will not work.

In my bot, I would like to make a button that calls **emergency numbers like 911, 999, or 112**.

Here's what I have tried so far (Hungary: 36, Budapest:1, emergency number:112):

- +361112 => X
- +112    => X
- +36112  => X
- 112     => X

In all above cases the call will be dropped or the payload will not show in Messenger, so it does not work.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: My guess would be that they deliberately decided not to support such numbers, because it has a huge abuse potential. And I can’t really see why this should happen from within a messenger bot in the first place ...

Comment: In our application, it would not be used for emergency calls, rather for our clients' short info number, which is a widely used concept. I don't really understand how these calls would be abused, since almost all of the real emergency services would be able to track you down by number. You can already spam these if you would want to.

Comment: Yes, but a nice shiny “Call 911 now!” button would probably increase the number of cases where people are dumb enough to try it without thinking about consequences much ... And I guess your client probably has a “normal” number to get to the same destination as well, right? So this would rather be a vanity thing ... and could be replaced by the “real” number then, if it is really that important.